# Mediaplayer-changing song change not working delphi 2010

Tags: delphi

i have a few forms in delphi 2010, and a media player on the first, called frmLogin. i used a mainmenu component to change the song playing and by calling a procedure from the first form. The problem is that after adding a new form and using the exact same code I used in the other forms, the song no longer changes.

```
procedure TfrmLogin.MC;   //procedure used to change song
begin
  mp1.close;
  mp1.FileName := strack;
  mp1.Open;
  mp1.Play;
end;
```

the code below is from the new form that was added

```
procedure TfrmMembers.MichaelJacksonAlone1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  strack := 'Song.wav';
  frmLogin.MC;
end;

procedure TfrmMembers.okyoGhoulseason11Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  strack := 'Tokyo ghoul season 1 theme.mp3';
  frmLogin.MC;
```

Comment: Do you see the `(Sender: TObject)` part of the procedures? They are parameters. Give your procedure `MC` a parameter, too, so you can just pass the filename to it instead of relying on a separate variable. I.e. `procedure TfrmLogin.MC(strack: String);`

Comment: When you say **song no longer changes** do you mean that same song start playing again from start or that nothing happens. If it is former than in your second form you are not changing the same `strack` variable as it is not declared as global variable but instead a separate variable which so happens to have the same name.  If it is the later then your `frmLogin` does not reference to your first form. This could happen if you redeclare `frmLogin` as new variable in the unit of your second form.

Comment: @AmigoJack, thanks i will try parameter passing to see if it works.